# Generate a random symmetric tensor in python

Tags: python, random, tensorflow, tensor, symmetric

I want to generate a random (gaussian) tensor symmetric with respect to all the permutations of the axes. In the end I want all the entries with the same distribution, so tricks like summing over all the permutation and rescaling by sqrt(k!), where k is the order of my tensor, don't work. eg:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations

noise_buffer = np.random.normal(size=n*n*n).reshape(n,n,n)/np.sqrt(6);
noise = np.zeros([n,n,n]);
for i in permutations([0,1,2]):
    noise += np.transpose(noise_buffer,axes=list(i))
```

I could loop over all the coordinates (-1) and rescale opportunely, but this is time consuming.

Do you know any library where this is implemented? or do you know any fast implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in time linear with the tensor size (`d^n`, avoiding the factorial overhead of generating all permutations) with quite a simple element wise approach, that also directly lets you choose the entry distribution:

```py
import itertools
import collections
import numpy as np

def random_symmetric(d, ndim, seed=None):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    # choose your desired distribution here
    value_store = collections.defaultdict(rng.normal)
    x = np.empty((d,) * ndim, dtype=np.float64)
    for coo in itertools.product(range(d), repeat=ndim):
        key = [0] * d
        for i in coo:
            key[i] += 1
        key = tuple(key)
        x[coo] = value_store[key]
    return x
```

to explain, you simply visit each element and its coordinate, 'hash' the coordinate into its respective permutation group, then generate or retrieve the random value for that permutation group. For example the coordinate `(0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1)` would have key `(3, 3, 1)` since it has 3 zeros, 3 ones and 1 two. The total number of unique elements generated will be `comb(ndim + d - 1, d - 1)`.

`x = random_symmetric(3, 12)` which is >1/2 million entries takes about 0.3sec. A cython/numba version should be very simple to adapt and likely much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method you present works; it just needs a small modification.

Use the fact that the sum of normal random variables, is another normal random variable with the variances summed, [e.g. see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)

The problem, it seems, was that you want the entries of noise to come from a certain distribution, but if you take noise_buffer from that distribution, then noise will have a different distribution.

The solution is to use a different distribution (specifically, normal, with standard deviation reduced by a factor of 1/sqrt(k!) ) for noise_buffer, then noise will have the right distribution.